# Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:bloc_simple/blocs/product_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductListScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shopping"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed:  ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/cart"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
        ],
      ),
      body: buildProductList(),
    );
  }

  buildProductList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      initialData: productBloc.getAll(),
      stream: productBloc.getStream,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        return snapshot.data.length>0?buildProductListItems(snapshot):Center(child: Text("oops.."),);
      },
    );
  }

  buildProductListItems(AsyncSnapshot<Object> snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,index){
          var list = snapshot.data;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(list[index].name),
          );
        });

  }

}
class ProductBloc{
  final productStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get getStream => productStreamController.stream;

  List<Product>? getAll(){
    return ProductService.getAll();
  }
}


final productBloc = ProductBloc();
```

here is error message

lib/screens/product_list_screen.dart:25:30: Error: The getter'length' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.
return snapshot.data.length>0?buildProductListItems(snapshot):Center(child: Text("oops.."),);
^^^^^^
lib/screens/product_list_screen.dart:25:61: Error: The argument type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AsyncSnapshot' because 'Object?' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.
- 'AsyncSnapshot' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart' ('/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart').
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
return snapshot.data.length>0?buildProductListItems(snapshot):Center(child: Text("oops.."),);
^
lib/screens/product_list_screen.dart:32:34: Error: The getter 'lenght' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'lenght'.
itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
^^^^^^
lib/screens/product_list_screen.dart:36:29: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
title: Text(list[index].name),

Comment: You need to define the object type for your StreamBuilder. For example: `StreamBuilder<List<Product>>(...)` .

Comment: Sorry i tried but nothing hapnd

Comment: Please show what you have in the function `productBloc.getStream`

Comment: class ProductBloc{
  final productStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get getStream => productStreamController.stream;

  List<Product>? getAll(){
    return ProductService.getAll();
  }
}


final productBloc = ProductBloc();  @WilsonToribio